# " Error in the installation of gam model?"

Tags: r

I am using the GAM package in **RStudio 1.3.1093** for the analysis of my data, I install the GAM package in my **Rstudio**, but when I call the library of GAM I got the following error,

```
library(gam)
```

Loading required package: foreach

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘foreach’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
> there is no package called ‘iterators’
> Error: package ‘foreach’ could not be loaded

But as apply this gam in my analysis I got the following error as:

> Error in gam(data ~ s(tt) + s(ye) + DC + BH) : could not find function "gam"**
> please help me in solving my problem.

Comment: Reopen R and install `foreach` package first and then install `gam`.

Comment: Thanks a lot **Bappa Das** its really works n solve my problem.